# Windows 7 OSQL Batch

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, osql

I have just got a new work PC from running Windows 7. I have installed SQL Server 2008 and I have a batch file that runs an OSQL command as follow:

```
osql -S MyServer -E -d MSDB -n -o results.txt -i MyScript.sql
```

For some reason it is giving me exception below:

```
Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  126: The specified module could not be found. (SQL Server Native Client 10.0, C:\Windows\system32\sqlncli10.dll).
```

I am not sure what the issue is and I have even tried to run the batch file using 'Run as administrator'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSQL is being deprecated; I would consider converting your code to use sqlcmd or PowerShell. However if you're missing SQL native client you might consider adding it. You can download the sqlncli.msi file for your platform from [this URL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44272) (more than halfway down the page).

Comment: Thanks for the link and also letting me know that it is deprecated.

Comment: Updated the link. The component has been distributed through SQL Server "Feature Packs" and there are new versions of those "Feature Packs" for each Service Pack release of SQL Server.